# Why Browser compatibility testing comes in NFR?

Tags: requirements, hp-quality-center, software-quality, manual-testing

I am making a SRS and as per the research that I have done on Non Functional Requirements "Browser compatibility" testing comes in [NFR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_tests) . Please explain why we take "Browser compatibility" in NFR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this link you can under stand, For functional testing we test each and every functionality(how the product should behave),..in non functional testing(HOW THE APPLICATION IS WORKING) we test load,stress...so its comes under NFR.

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-cross-browser-testing-tools-to-ease-your-browser-compatibility-testing-efforts/

http://www.guru99.com/compatibility-testing.html

```
Initial phase of compatibility testing is to define the set of environments or platforms the application is expected to work on.
Tester should have enough knowledge on the platforms / software / hardware to understand the expected application behavior under different configurations.
Environment needs to be set-up for testing with different platforms, devices, networks to check whether your application runs well under different configurations.
Report the bugs .Fix the defects. Re-test to confirm defect fixing.
```

Answer (score 1):

Functional requirement is about how the product should behave. it is about what is the expected output for a given set of initial conditions and actions. And we functional requirement takes on business view on it. If you are building a software to run a dental office, functional requirements are going to be about adding a patient, taking appointments etc.

Non-functional Requirements on the other end is not going to be about the "business behaviour" but more about the platform on which the software will run, the ergonomic of the product or the performance (although for performance, it can become sort of "functional" if the soft is useless above a certain response time)

Back to Browser compatibility, this is not about the behaviour of the product. For our dental office example, the dentist does not really care if it will run correctly on Chrome or Firefox. That is not what he is looking for to run his business. Nevertheless, if your implementation or test conclude that the soft runs ok only on Chrome, then you will have to advice use this browser. But this has nothing to do with the functions of the products.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/tools-browser-compatibility-check/

Compatibility testing, part of software non-functional tests, is testing conducted on the application to evaluate the application's compatibility with the computing environment. Computing environment may contain some or all of the below mentioned elements:

```
Computing capacity of Hardware Platform (IBM 360, HP 9000, etc.)..
Bandwidth handling capacity of networking hardware
Compatibility of peripherals (Printer, DVD drive, etc.)
Operating systems (Linux, Windows, Mac etc.)
Database (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)
Other System Software (Web server, networking/ messaging tool, etc.)
Browser compatibility (Chrome, Firefox, Netscape, Internet Explorer, Safari, etc.)
```